# Find index of a second character occurrence in a string?

Tags: java, string

How do I find the *second* index of a character in a string. For instance:

```
String a="aa{aaaaaaa{aaa}";
```

I'd like to find the index value of the second `{`. Here it is 10.

Comment: `a.indexOf('{', a.indexOf('{' + 1);`

Comment: Either regexp or two indexOfs (sorry no regexp, you need to find the index)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int,%20int%29

Comment: if it is allways the last index you need try [lastIndexOf("{")](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_lastindexof.htm)

Comment: it showing index 2  @JigarJoshi

Comment: @mekala see updated :)

Comment: @mekala Why don't you even think from clues ? You need  a working line to just past in your project ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Find the first one, move one right, then find the next one from there. That's the second :)

```
int secondIndex = a.indexOf('{', a.indexOf('{')+1);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to overloaded version of `indexOf()`, which takes the starting index as 2nd parameter.

```
str.indexOf("{", str.indexOf("{") + 1);
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but doesn't an overloaded message reside in the same class as the method that it overloads? That would involve changing the code of class `String`. How can one do that? Maybe you mean _override_ (and not _overload_). If you do, then how can you override a method of class [java.lang.String](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) when that class is a `final` class? But what I'm ___really___ curious about is why an unimplementable answer received four up-votes.